# c# child constructor calls parent constructor depending on a value

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

This is my problem, I have it sorted, but I think that there is a better way of doing this:

I have the following code:

```cs
public class A
{
    public A(int paramA, int paramB)
    {
       ParamA = paramA;
       ParamB = paramB;
    }

    public int ParamA { get; set; }
    public int ParamB { get; set; }
}
```

I also have the following code:

```cs
public class B : A
{
    public B(int c, int d, int paramA, int paramB)
    {
        C = c;
        D = d;
        if (C == 0)
        {
            ParamA = paramA - D;
            ParamB = paramB;
        }
        else
        {
            ParamA = paramA;
            ParamB = paramB;
        }
    }

    public int C { get; set; }
    public int D { get; set; }
}
```

In other words, the value assigned to ParamA depends on the value of `C`. I know that you can do something like `public B(int c, int d, int paramA, int paramB) : base(paramA, paramB)`, but that's not what I want, as `paramA` will be assigned to `ParamA` whatever `C` is. The code works, but is there other better way of doing it?

Edit: responses to the comments:

Yes, it has a parameterless constructor that is not in the code.
Yes, properties are mutable, that is on purpose, there is more code.
At this stage, I am trying to achieve a clean code, just that in child class parent parameters depend on some specific values in child parameters.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. `B.B` _has_ to call `A.A(int,int)` because `A` doesn't have a parameterless ctor. Does your actual code have a parameterless ctor that you haven't included in your post?

Comment: Also, your properties are both public and mutable, so there's nothing stopping _anyone_ from simply overwriting the `ParamA` and `ParamB` properties after construction.

Comment: BTW, you can avoid the _human-visual-ambiguity_ of assigning properties with the same names as parameters by using `this.` to make it clear you're setting an instance property or field instead of overwriting the parameter value.

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve, other than chaing the `ParamA` value in the inherited class? Is there any other logic `B` will perform in the constructor that impacts `A`?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you're using this, like where are the parameters coming from? This feels a little janky. Does `B` definately have an `Is a` relationship with `A`, or should it be a `Has a` relationship?

Comment: so class A is a standard base mortgage, and class B is a mortgage with some overpayment calculations, if the overpayment is to reduce the monthly payments, the calculations done for the standard base mortgage are still valid if the initial loan is reduced by the overpayment

Comment: `Trying to achieve clean code` is first trap. Your constructors do some other job, instead of initialize only. So it violates "clean" meanings. `A`, `B`, `c`, `d` is second trap. Oversimplifying leads to context loss, which hardens to understand what you want and how to help you properly. For now, to avoid further tonns of clarifyings, you may try edit code example by providing original code with meaningful namings, including both declaration and usage examples, just to be able at least to properly reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously I don't know your exact reasons for doing so, but I'd be inclined to try and have just a single `Mortgage` class with the overpayment logic on it and maybe use a flag to identify there is an overpayment.

That aside, you could do something like the following:

```
public class A
{
    public A(int paramA, int paramB)
    {
        ParamA = paramA;
        ParamB = paramB;
    }

    public int ParamA { get; set; }

    public int ParamB { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B(int c, int d, int paramA, int paramB) 
        : base(paramA, paramB)
    {
        C = c;
        D = d;
        
        if (C == 0)
        {
            ParamA -= D;
        }
    }

    public int C { get; set; }

    public int D { get; set; }
}
```

You *could* also check if `C == 0` in the `base` call but I don't advise it (less readable for a start in my opinion).

```
public class B : A
{
    public B(int c, int d, int paramA, int paramB) 
        : base(c == 0 ? paramA - d : paramA , paramB)
    {
        C = c;
        D = d;
    }

    public int C { get; set; }

    public int D { get; set; }
}
```